Trying to debug why not-found reported for a next.js API after deploy
Same code (a dynamic route) runs locally but once I deploy it to a VPS server, even if I try to run in dev mode I directly get not-found:

A static non API route works as it can be seen in /test
I have the same code locally and it works. Also it can be seen next is immediately returning not-found, no other client code get executed for this route  only the app router does not respond for some reason. Any way to debug this with more logs ?
In my proj I have app/api/todo/route.ts

Found out the difference was the OS where this got deployed. On VPS linux Route.ts naming caused the issue (instead of route.ts)
